# How to differentiate between a resident of southern California and a resident of southern Baja California?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, gentilicio

In "Smart Spanish for Tontos Americanos", it says that a person from Northern Baja California is called a "bajacaliforniano(a)" whereas someone from Southern Baja California is called a "sudcaliforniano(a)"

So what is a person from the southern part of the state of California in the United States called - someone from L.A. or San Diego or Redlands or such?

Comment: What is Northern Baja California? I see in Wikipedia in Spanish [Baja California](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baja_California) with _bajacaliforniano_ (included in the [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4o4bUAc)) and [Baja California Sur](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baja_California_Sur) with _sudcaliforniano_ (not included).

Comment: After reading the question my mind was only capable to think "bajacalifornilísticoexpialidoso". :-)

Comment: @fedorqui: I had never heard of Baja California broken up into two regions, either, but that's from the book referenced. The question remains the same, though, with "sudcaliforniano" sounding to me like what you would call Angelinos (and all other Californians up to at least Santa Barbara).

Comment: I don't think there is such a demonym. In general, they just apply to real regions, not to parts of it. For cases like this I would use _californiano del sur_. But maybe there is something more specific that I am not aware of.

Comment: Are you asking about southern Baja California, or Baja California Sur? Or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in comments, México has two regions with this name:

- [Baja California (Norte)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baja_California), whose demonym is "*bajacaliforniano/a*"
- [Baja California Sur](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baja_California_Sur), whose demonym is "*sudcaliforniano/a*"

[image]

You want to know how to call people from the south of [California](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/California), in United States. People from that state are called "*californiano/a*", but there is no such demonym to refer to a part of it.

For such cases, we use *del sur*, *del norte* or whatever. So, in this case, I would go for "***californiano del sur***". This gives us, Spanish speakers, a very clear view of the situation: you mention the gentilic and then add the cardinal point.